# update database table ltrim rtrim too slow

Tags: database, sybase

I have a table with 500000 records aprox. I need to update on of the fields and i'm using the follow instruction:

```
update myTable set myField = ltrim(rtrim(myField))
```

But the instruction takes one hour excecuting. I've tried using where clause ex:

```
update myTable set myField = ltrim(rtrim(myField)) where myPrimaryKey >= 0 and myPrimaryKey <= 50000
```

But the execution time is very slow too.

Any ideas? How can I improve the performance of update?
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a `non-clustered index` over `myField` temporarily for this update alone and try this update script.

Comment: I already have a non-clustered index on myField and I updated statistics too. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I reduce the time using a CURSOR.

```
DECLARE cursor_prueba CURSOR FOR
select A, B, C from MyTable order by A
' A is PrimaryKey

OPEN cursor_prueba
FETCH cursor_prueba INTO @varA, @varB, @varC

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    update MyTable set B = ltrim(rtrim(B)), C = ltrim(rtrim(C)) where A = @varA

    FETCH cursor_prueba INTO @varA, @varB, @varC
END

CLOSE cursor_prueba
DEALLOCATE cursor_prueba
```

I hope this helps.
Regards everybody.